# VK open api, wall.post невозможно прикрепить фото, почему?

Tags: javascript, вконтакте, api

Отправляю запрос, в переменной data содержится результат вызова метода photos.saveWallPhoto, ошибок нет. В результате я не вижу фото, почему?

```
VK.Api.call('wall.post', {
    v: "3.0",
    owner_id: data.response[0].owner_id,
    message: 'Текст поста',
    attachments: 'photo' + data.response[0].owner_id + '_' + data.response[0].id
}, function (data) {

});
```